# I want to get category and put in the page title in magento

Tags: magento, title

this is the code that i want to modify(in head.phtml):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

I want to get category and put in title.My code is:

```
?php
$currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category");
?>
<?php $_title = $currentCategory->getName(); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $_title ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

It works well when I'm in the category item but the home page does not open it anymore.
I think $_title is empty or something like that. I tried to implement if statement but is the same problem.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category')) : ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category"); ?>
<?php $_title = $currentCategory->getName(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php $_title = $this->getTitle(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this- >getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $_title ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

Comment: it's ok now, my first page work, but i have new issues. I will come back later with details.

Comment: Ok Sure I will help you, Can You accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: now the problem is: my title i want to be "Best quality $_title", but when i have a category "disease", it sounds strange "Best quality disease". I wonder if I'm still making an if in the first if to insert another variable and the title to be "Products for $ _newTitle".

Answer (score 5):

You can Manage the meta details from the admin itself. Admin > Catalog > Manage Category. You don't need to modify any template file.

[image: Manage the meta info]

```
Mage::registry("current_category");
```

Above code returns the current category object. So on all the pages except the category ones, above registry will have no existence. So you will get error on all pages except the Category Pages.